# How to create common alias for all cells in a column in Excel automatically through scripting

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel workbook with close to 90 columns. I would like to create column alias for each column in the workbook, so that it will be easier for me to use the respective columns in formulas.

Normally, I would select each column in the workbook and type in my alias for the column into the Cell Reference Bar at the top

Is there a way to do this automatically, because i have a lot of columns? Especially in Python ?

I tried the pandas.Series.to_excel function which has the header attribute. However all it does is change the column names to the string specified and does not modify the alias for all the cells in the column.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: In VBA you can shorthand it as Range(...).Name = "abc"

Comment: Try exploring the openpyxl framework in Python

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...

To name each of the columns something slightly different you can use a for-loop which contains an incrementing number that's added to the column name.

There are loads of examples of this available online, here's a really rough illustrative example:

`num = 0
for header in column:
    num +=1
    header = header+str(num)`

I don't think you need to program this for just 90 columns in one book though tbh. 
You could name the first 3 columns, select the three named cells, and then drag right when you see the + symbol in the bottom right corner of the most rightern cell of the three selected.
Dragging across 90 cells should only take one second.

Once you've named the 90 columns, you can always select row#1 and do some ctrl+h on it to change the header names later.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, is your data in a table, or named range?

I'm kind of assuming a table (which could make this a snap) because, as a column heading in a (named) range, the 'header' (or alias, if I understand) isn't "connected" to the underlying data, as it would be in a table...

Can you provide an example of how you would (or expect to) use the 'column alias' in a formula?